# WPF bind to collection of controls

Tags: wpf, binding

I want to do a binding to a collection of homemade custom controls.I've a collection of objects (called Parameters), each one of these should be presented in a panel by a custom control.
I have the following in my main window:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Parameters}">  
</ItemsControl>
```

And I have a resource file to declare how to view each Parameter object:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type path:Parameter}">
    <Grid>              
        <myControls:MyUserControl
            Parameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        </myControls:MyUserUserControl> 
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

My control takes a Parameter so I want to bind it to itself for every item in the collection. How can I do that binding?

Comment: Change the binding expression for Parameter to {Binding}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a DataTemplate that serves as ItemTemplate in an ItemsControl, the DataContext holds the individual items of the source collection. Hence the binding should look like this:

```
<myControls:MyUserControl Parameter="{Binding}" />
```

and the ItemsControl may be written like this to explicitly use the DataTemplate:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Parameters}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>              
                <myControls:MyUserControl Parameter="{Binding}" /> 
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```